# Spring SAML2 Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler

Tags: spring-security, saml

I am using Spring Security v5.5.1 SAML2 code for SAML support.  I have a working solution using the older Spring security extension, but I am "upgrading".

I have the SP initiated and IDP initiated flows working, but I cannot figure out how to configure the success handler redirect URL.  It defaults to "/".  I do not understand how I can access the `Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter` and/or the `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` to override the URL.

I set a default `RelayState` on the IDP and it does get sent with the assertions, but Spring does not appear to use it.

Also, using the older extension, I could store the SAML request in a DB and retrieve it when the response comes in since my app does not use sessions.  I have not found a way to do the same here.

Here are my auth provider and relaying party registration as gleened from the docs and samples I found:

```
OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider();
authenticationProvider.setAssertionValidator( OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.createDefaultAssertionValidator( assertionToken -> {
                    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put( CLOCK_SKEW, Duration.ofMinutes(10).toMillis());

                    String recipient = assertionToken.getToken().getRelyingPartyRegistration().getAssertionConsumerServiceLocation();
                    params.put( SAML2AssertionValidationParameters.SC_VALID_RECIPIENTS, Collections.singleton(recipient));

                    String audience = assertionToken.getToken().getRelyingPartyRegistration().getAssertionConsumerServiceLocation();
                    params.put( SAML2AssertionValidationParameters.COND_VALID_AUDIENCES, Collections.singleton( "blah"));

                    return new ValidationContext( params);
                })
        );

Converter<HttpServletRequest, RelyingPartyRegistration> relyingPartyRegistrationResolver =
        new DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver( relyingPartyRegistrationRepository);

Saml2MetadataFilter filter = new Saml2MetadataFilter(
                relyingPartyRegistrationResolver,
                new OpenSamlMetadataResolver());

http
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers( "/saml2/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers( "/login/**").permitAll()
    .and()
    .saml2Login( saml2 -> saml2.authenticationManager( new ProviderManager( authenticationProvider)))
    .addFilterBefore( filter, Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

```
RelyingPartyRegistration registration = RelyingPartyRegistration
        .withRegistrationId("blah")
        .assertionConsumerServiceLocation( getAssertionRecipient( environment, "blah"))
        .signingX509Credentials( c -> c.add( credentialSp))
        .decryptionX509Credentials( c -> c.add( decryptSp))
        .assertingPartyDetails(party -> party
            .entityId("blah")
            .singleSignOnServiceLocation("https://sso.stuff/samlstuff")
            .wantAuthnRequestsSigned( false)
            .verificationX509Credentials( c -> c.add( credential))
        )
        .build();
```

I imagine that I can do the same as before somehow, but for all the docs that are supplied, it is difficult to make sense of much of it.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show your whole `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method or `SecurityFilterChain` bean?

Comment: Edited with configure method additions

Comment: Have you tried defining an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` inside your `saml2Login` configuration? Upon login successful, it should be called and you can specify the URL that you want to forward the user

Comment: I didn't even notice that!  :). I will give it a shot.

Comment: Let me know if it works so we can write a definitive answer to help others that may have the same question

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should try a .successHandler(<my_successhandler>)

```
http
.sessionManagement()
.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
.and()
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers( "/saml2/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers( "/login/**").permitAll()
.and()
.saml2Login()
.successHandler(mySamlLoginSuccessHandler)
```

with

```
class MySamlLoginSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
   MySamlLoginSuccessHandler() {
      super('/path/to/success')
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this it worked for me.
.saml2Login( saml2 -> {saml2.authenticationManager( new ProviderManager( authenticationProvider); saml2.defaultSuccessUrl("url") }))

Answer (score 0):

The following is how I set it

```
httpSecurity
 .saml2Login()
   .successHandler(CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandlerBean())
   .relyingPartyRegistrationRepository(relyingPartyRegistrationRepository())
   .authenticationManager(new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider))
   .loginPage("/abc/saml_login");
```

In spring 6.x, I am using

```
httpSecurity
.saml2Login(saml2 -> saml2.successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
.relyingPartyRegistrationRepository(relyingPartyRegistrationRepository())
.authenticationManager(new ProviderManager(new OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider()))
.loginPage("/abc/saml_login"));
```

Comment: It doesn't work with Spring Security 5.7.2. Success handler method has been removed.